# I have a simple Python Calc and I need a "quit" choice

Tags: python, function, calculator

```
# Program make a simple calculator

# This function adds two numbers
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

# This function subtracts two numbers
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

# This function multiplies two numbers
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

# This function divides two numbers
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

print("İşlem seçiniz.")
print("1.Toplama")
print("2.Çıkarma")
print("3.Çarpma")
print("4.Bölme")

while True:
    # Take input from the user
    choice = input("Seçim yapınız(1/2/3/4): ")

    # Check if choice is one of the four options
    if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
        num1 = float(input("İlk numarayı giriniz: "))
        num2 = float(input("İkinci numarayı giriniz: "))

        if choice == '1':
            print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))

        elif choice == '2':
            print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract(num1, num2))

        elif choice == '3':
            print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2))

        elif choice == '4':
            print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2))

    else:
        print("Hatalı Giriş")
```

This is my simple calc with a def func an i need a quit/break choice in menu, i want a choice code like this

```
    def run():
        while True:
            choice = get_input()
            if choice == "a":
                # do something
            elif choice == "q":
                return

    if __name__ == "
__main__":
    run()
```

I would be really grateful if someone helps me. Thank you.

*This is my school homework, I would really appreciate it if you could explain more about the codes. I try to improve myself as much as I can, it makes me sad to be unable to do something as simple as this, but I need your help. Wish me luck to improve. And take care of your health, stay at home*

Comment: Why don't you add a "q" choice?

Comment: @DYZ when i add "q" in to the choice its turn a math operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an option to break from while loop on input if user say enters a q?

```
elif(x == "q"):
   break
```

Answer (score 2):

You could import sys module and exit the code in following way:

```
import sys

def run():
    # do stuff
    if choice == "q":
        sys.exit() # this exits the python program
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few menus before, my favorite option in this case would be to put the menu options inside it's own function, and have it return the choice back to the main function. Like this:

```
def multiply(number1, number2):
    return number1 * number2

def showmenu():
    print("1. Multiply")
    print("2. Quit")
    return input("Choice:")

def main():
    playing = True

    num1 = 5
    num2 = 3

    while playing:
        choice = showmenu()

        if choice == '1':
            print(f'{num1} * {num2} = {multiply(num1,num2)}')

        elif choice == '2':
            print("Quitting!")
            playing = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```